# Couldn't find Internship without an ID error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi so I'm really new to rails and I am trying to figure out how to use this gem https://github.com/jonhue/acts_as_favoritor.

At the moment I am trying to get a student to favourite an internship.

My favourites controller looks like this

```html
    class FavouritesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @internship = Internship.find(params[:id])
        current_student.favourite(internship)
        redirect_to_show
    end

    def show
        current_students.all_favourites
    end

end
```

My routes look like this

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :favourites
  devise_for :students
  resources :internships
  devise_for :companies
  # For details on the DSL ava
```

And my button to add an internship shown in the index is this

```html
<td><%= link_to 'favourite', new_favourite_path %></td>
```

Using the gem I have put in the models acts_as_favoritor in the student model and acts_as_favoritable in the internship model. I have been banging my head against the wall for ages trying to understand how to write methods from so if someone could please help me out, Thank you heaps!

Answer (score 1):

I think if I were you, I would make my routes something like:

```
resources :internships do 
  member do 
    post :favorite
    post :unfavorite
  end
end
```

Which will give you among other things:

```
  favorite_internship POST   /internships/:id/favorite(.:format)     internships#favorite
unfavorite_internship POST   /internships/:id/unfavorite(.:format)   internships#unfavorite
          internships GET    /internships(.:format)                  internships#index
                      POST   /internships(.:format)                  internships#create
       new_internship GET    /internships/new(.:format)              internships#new
      edit_internship GET    /internships/:id/edit(.:format)         internships#edit
           internship GET    /internships/:id(.:format)              internships#show
                      PATCH  /internships/:id(.:format)              internships#update
                      PUT    /internships/:id(.:format)              internships#update
                      DELETE /internships/:id(.:format)              internships#destroy
```

Then in your view, you would do something along the lines of:

```
<td>
  <% if current_student.favorited?(internship) %>
    <%= link_to 'unfavourite', unfavorite_internship_path(internship), method: :post %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'favourite', favorite_internship_path(internship), method: :post %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

This, naturally, assumes you have access to `current_student` and `internship` in your view.

Then, in your `InternshipsController`, you would do something like:

```
class InternshipsController < ApplicationController

  def favorite
    @internship = Internship.find(params[:id])
    current_student.favorite(@internship)
    # redirect somewhere
  end

  def unfavorite
    @internship = Internship.find(params[:id])
    current_students.unfavorite(@internship)
    # redirect somewhere
  end

end
```

Now, `favorite` and `unfavorite` are not very restful. So, I guess you could do:

```
resources :internships do 
  scope module: :internships do 
    resources :favorites, only: [:create] do 
      collection do 
        delete '/', action: :destroy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which would give you:

```
internship_favorites DELETE /internships/:internship_id/favorites(.:format)   internships/favorites#destroy
                     POST   /internships/:internship_id/favorites(.:format)   internships/favorites#create
         internships GET    /internships(.:format)                            internships#index
                     POST   /internships(.:format)                            internships#create
      new_internship GET    /internships/new(.:format)                        internships#new
     edit_internship GET    /internships/:id/edit(.:format)                   internships#edit
          internship GET    /internships/:id(.:format)                        internships#show
                     PATCH  /internships/:id(.:format)                        internships#update
                     PUT    /internships/:id(.:format)                        internships#update
                     DELETE /internships/:id(.:format)                        internships#destroy
```

Then you would need a `Internships::FavoritesController` something like:

```
# in app/controllers/internships/favorites_controller.rb
class Internships::FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @internship = Internship.find(params[:internship_id])
    current_student.favorite(@internship)
    # redirect somewhere
  end

  def destroy
    @internship = Internship.find(params[:internship_id])
    current_students.unfavorite(@internship)
    # redirect somewhere
  end

end
```

Then in your view, it would be more like:

```
<td>
  <% if current_student.favorited?(internship) %>
    <%= link_to 'unfavourite', internship_favorites_path(internship), method: :delete %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'favourite', internship_favorites_path(internship), method: :post %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```